# Which is the best way to create an html image using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an html image using JavaScript dynamically.

Is there any difference in the below two methods ?

1)

```
var Img = document.createElement("img");
Img.setAttribute('src', 'myImageSrc');
document.body.appendChild(Img);
```

2)

```
var Img = new Image();
Img.src = 'myImageSrc';
```

Which one is the best way ? 
Also, what happens when we use `new Image()` apart from the method which accepts arguments (eg : `new Image(1,1)`) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference, this are different methods to assign src to image.
Those 2 parameters in new Image are nothing but width and height.

Comment: So, what will be the default value for width and height, when we do not set them, ie, just using new Image() ?

Comment: y dont you give it a try ?

According to me, it will take natural width and height of image.